# Keycloak: Create role with attributes in Java Client

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to create a client role in Keycloak(11.0.0) with keycloak-admin-client (11.0.0) with a few custom attributes.
The role gets created, but the attribute field is simply ignored by Keycloak. Has anybody an idea how to get it working?

This is the simplified code I am using:

```
public void createRole(String name) {
    RoleRepresentation roleRepresentation = new RoleRepresentation();
    Map<String, List<String>> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    attributes.put("att1", Collections.singletonList("attribute1"));
    attributes.put("att2", Collections.singletonList("attribute2"));
    roleRepresentation.setAttributes(attributes);
    roleRepresentation.setClientRole(true);
    roleRepresentation.setName(name);
    realm.clients().get(client.getId()).roles().create(roleRepresentation);
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone who is struggling with the same problem:
I just found a workaround myself. You need to update the newly created role with the same object and it works.

```
public void createRole(String name) {
        RoleRepresentation roleRepresentation = new RoleRepresentation();
        Map<String, List<String>> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        attributes.put("att1", Collections.singletonList("attribute1"));
        attributes.put("att2", Collections.singletonList("attribute2"));
        roleRepresentation.setAttributes(attributes);
        roleRepresentation.setClientRole(true);
        roleRepresentation.setName(name);
        realm.clients().get(client.getId()).roles().create(roleRepresentation);
        
        // Now update the new role immediately
        RoleResource roleResource = realm.clients().get(client.getId()).roles().get(name);
        roleResource.update(roleRepresentation);
    }
```